# HTML Table Overflow Into Adjacent Div

Tags: visualforce, pdf, html, css, overflow

I have a table that is 2 pages long. I want the data on the second page, to overflow into a second div, on the first page. Side by side. See pictures. Is this possible?

One stipulation is that I am generating it as a PDF so JavaScript is out of the picture.

I am using `apex:repeat` so when I create two tables, in two divs, I get the same data twice side by side. Is there a way to use `repeat` and overflow? Or will I have to change the table to all HTML?

What I want it to look like:
[image: what I want it to look like]

UPDATE:
I did ask this question in Stack Overflow due to it's HTML/CSS [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468284/html-table-overflow-into-adjacent-div/41468694?noredirect=1#comment70143447_41468694).

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;">
<table>
    <tbody>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Ext.</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <apex:repeat value="{!allPeople}" var="depts">
            <th colspan="5" id="department">{!depts}</th>
            <apex:repeat value="{!allPeople[depts]}" var="person">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!person.Name}</td>
                    <td>{!person.Title}</td>
                    <td>{!person.Extension}</td>
                    <td>{!person.Phone}</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>             
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @AdrianLarson I did and people got caught up on the apex:repeat and apex:page....The advice I got was HTML specific and was to create two tables, in two divs, but this doesn't work with repeat so I figured I would ask here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, interesting, when I tried the two tables it just repeated the same data on both sides. If you say it can be done, I will fiddle around with the two tables some more!

Comment: @AdrianLarson valid point, I updated the question!

Comment: I think a **[chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51191/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-olivia)** will be necessary to have any hope of resolving this issue.

Comment: @javanoob I have tried the two tables and using a float: left/ float: right but the issue is the `repeat`. I can't make two tables with different data.

Comment: I think you're going to need to use a custom controller with "pagination" of sorts to resolve your issue. Even if you can wrap into another column, if on the same page, your 2nd table won't have a new header unless you do this in a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a shot at this one and came up with the below solution. Please update it according to your needs:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class PdfController {

    public List<Contact> conList{get;set;}

    public PdfController() {
        conList = [SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Contact];
    }
}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="PdfController"
            renderAs="pdf" 
            applyBodyTag="false"
            showHeader="false" 
            sidebar="false">
    <apex:variable var="recsPerPage" value="{!20}"></apex:variable>
    <apex:variable var="pageNum" value="{!0}"></apex:variable>

    <body>

        <apex:repeat value="{!conList}" var="dummy" 
                        first="{!recsPerPage * pageNum}" 
                        rows="{!recsPerPage}">

            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!pageNum * recsPerPage < conList.size}">

                <table id="leftTable" style="width: 50%;float:left;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>First Name</td>
                            <td>Last Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Left side table -->
                        <apex:repeat value="{!conList}" var="con" 
                                    first="{! (recsPerPage) * pageNum}" 
                                    rows="{!recsPerPage/2}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{!con.Id}</td>
                                <td>{!con.LastName}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!pageNum * recsPerPage <conList.size}">

                <table id="rightTable" style="width:50%;float:right;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>First Name</td>
                            <td>Last Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <!-- Right side table -->
                        <apex:repeat value="{!conList}" var="con" 
                                    first="{!((recsPerPage) * pageNum) + (recsPerPage/2)}" 
                                    rows="{!(recsPerPage/2)}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{!con.Id}</td>
                                <td>{!con.LastName}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:variable var="pageNum" value="{!pageNum +1}"></apex:variable>

            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! ((pageNum + 1) * recsPerPage) <= conList.size }">
                <p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:repeat>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Output:

[image]

This is totally possible because we can control how many rows we want to print using `first` and `rows` attribute of `apex:repeat` also we know how many rows we want to print per page.

I am using `apex:variable` tag to increment the temporary variables like page number and such..

Let me know if you have any questions on the code.

Hope this helps..

**UPDATE:**
I tested this on data spanning more than 20 pages and it is working fine.

Comment: Didn't know about the `first` and `rows` attributes. TIL.

Comment: @javanoob awesome code, I am messing around with it today to get the department names in there too. Great idea with the first and rows on repeat. I learn something new every day!